# MySQL-optimización: Seleccionar 2 registros máximo y mínimo en un rango de fecha

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente problema: necesito obtener 2 valores de odómetros de una tabla que almacena la información de un vehículo para calcular la distancia recorrida, cada tabla almacena una buena cantidad de registro por día (aproximadamente 5,000 registros por día) y actualmente utilizo la siguiente sintaxis para obtener los dos valores de odómetro

```sql
SELECT 
    (SELECT VO 
       FROM rawdata_357042066496572 
       WHERE event_time
       BETWEEN '2021-11-18T06:00:00' 
       AND '2021-11-19T23:00:00' 
       ORDER BY event_time 
       DESC LIMIT 1) as 'last',
    (SELECT VO
       FROM rawdata_357042066496572 
       WHERE event_time
       BETWEEN '2021-11-18T06:00:00' 
       AND '2021-11-19T23:00:00' 
       ORDER BY event_time 
       LIMIT 1) as 'first',
    (SELECT imei 
       FROM rawdata_357042066496572 
       WHERE event_time
       BETWEEN '2021-11-18T06:00:00' 
       AND '2021-11-19T23:00:00' 
       ORDER BY event_time 
       DESC LIMIT 1) as 'imei'
```

el cual me retorna la siguiente información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Eso es justo lo que deseo pero:** siento que no es la mejor forma de consultarlo ya que veo que se tarda al rededor de `1.56 segundos` y esto lo hago para un solo vehículo y deseo hacerlo para muchos vehículos usando la clausula `UNION ALL` para concatenar en la consulta el código anterior

Me inclino que la lentitud de la consulta se deba a que consulto rango de fechas y primero creo que lee todos los registros y luego solo me devuelve 1 con `LIMIT` pero no estoy seguro, si alguien me puede orientar se lo agradecería

**NOTA IMPORTANTE** : la consulta esta correcta me devuelve los datos que nesesito solo que se tarda al rededor de `1.56 segundos` a `1.60` segundos y se incrementar ese tiempo a medida que añado otros vehículos con la clausula `UNION ALL`.

**datos extra**

*event_time*: es un campo de fecha

*VO*: es un valor numerico del odometro

*rawdata_numero*: nombre de la tabla que almacena la información de cada vehículo

Comment: Utilice funciones de grupo min() y max() para las filas seleccionadas

Comment: Saludo @MauricioOrtega me podría ayudar con un ejemplo de esas funciones utilizando rango de fechas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilice funciones de agrupamiento sobre las columnas objetivo de su conjunto de filas

```
SELECT max(VO) as 'last',
   min(VO) as 'first',
   max(imei) as 'imei'
  FROM rawdata_357042066496572
 WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2021-11-18T06:00:00' AND '2021-11-19T23:00:00'
```

Para ampliar detalles: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Comment: estoy agradecido, ya lo probé y note la diferencia ahora en `0.50` a `0.60` segundo me realiza la consulta y probé para 2 y 3 unidades con la clausula UNION ALL y no se dispara el tiempo de respuesta siempre es mas rapido a como lo tenia anteriormente

Comment: ya lo califiqué y acepte la respuesta, gracias